# My PC has VGA/DVI-D but all new monitors are HDMI - How do I connect?

Tags: display, hdmi, desktop-computer, vga, dvi

I was going to get a new monitor for PC but it looks like they only connect via HDMI (or sometimes "Display Port"??). I'm fairly sure my PC is only VGA or DVI-D. Can I still connect them? I have a converter I used on the PS3 that went HDMI port from PS4 to VGA on TV -- can I use that?

Thanks for any help. Please explain any jargon since I don't have any knowledge of newer electronics. I also don't have a lot of money, trying to do this for around ~200-300.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI is DVI-D with content protection and a different plug.

So use a DVI-D to HDMI adapter. You can find them for less than 10 EUR. (No idea what currency your "200-300" are).

Comment: Of course, HDMI is a little more than just DVI with a different plug. That’s why this will definitely work but also be limited to 1920x1200.